# Get data if the database is empty?

Tags: php, database

Pay attention to the `options` array this array holds an array of properties on the database, there is a call for the database in the script it's not nessecary to add here, it retrieves the data because it's already on there...

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id'         => 'page_metabox',
    'fields'     => array(

        array(
            'name' => ''.$slider['properties']['title'].'',
            'desc' => 'Upload an image/pattern for the static area.',
            'id' => $prefix . 'text_BOMB',
            'type' => 'sortable',
            'options' => $slider['properties'],               
            'multiple' => true,
        ),
 );
```

The data HTML is outputted using a foreach and an input...

```
 <?php foreach ( $field['options'] as $value => $name ) : ?>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $field['id'].'[]' ?>" id="<?php echo $field['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"  />      
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is exactally what I want, I have a list of inputs for each property... then it hit me, what if its a new user and the data isnt on their database yet the foreach wont output anything and then there is no way to write it to the database... this is pretty noobish but that means an easier answer for you guys :p

Comment: why don't you use `count($field['options'])` to know if there is anything there, or `count($field['options']['fields'])` if it equals 0 then echo some empty input boxes for the user to use, you can further combine this with jQuery to add new dynamic fields for more properties.

Comment: Ok sounds good, how do I write it exactly (noob here).. `if(count($field['options'] == 0){ //mystuff} else { // else stuff}`

Comment: [Manual is your friend, if u don't know the syntax for a function check it up.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Can you just explain how to write it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **empty** - function:

```
<?php 
if (empty($field['options'])) {
    //do something when options are empty
}
else { //the array $field['options'] has something in it
    foreach ( $field['options'] as $value => $name ) : ?>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $field['id'].'[]' ?>" id="<?php echo $field['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"  />      
    <?php endforeach;
}
?>
```